# jquery tabs question

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I created jquery tabs for my website. I have some application buttons inside the content of one of my tabs.  When I click on one of the buttons (these buttons contains different links) it takes me away from my tab page and opens the content in another page. I do not want that so what do i need to do?

Comment: Where do you **want** the links to open? Are the links connecting to URLs on your own domain?

Comment: Hello! Since I see you are new to the site, I just wanted to give you a pointer to help you get a better answer to your question. First and foremost, please provide source code (keep it as small and simple as possible) demonstrating your problem. Unfortunately, we cannot debug code that we cannot see.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in

```
$(".btn").click(function() {

// Code to run goes here...

Return False // - Stops the link from firing
}
```

or using jquery you can do preventDefault...

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {

// code here...

e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: The buttons are inside a report viewer webpart

Comment: In url1 I have report viewer web part and it hosts my links.

Comment: Yeah I was just looking at that question... :D You really need to be more informative with your questions. Are you you are trying to use ajax to fetch data across different domains...?

Comment: You might need to preload the Iframes with your data... rather than fetching the data onClick? Ill post an answer...

Comment: is there a way to do this using javascript? the code you provided did not work. i can set urls on my button images.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full">
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#frame-1").attr("src","http://www.google.com");
    $("#frame-2").attr("src","http://www.google.com");
    $("#frame-3").attr("src","http://www.google.com");
    $("#frame-4").attr("src","http://www.google.com");
    $("#tabs").tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">site1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">site2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">site3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">site4</a></li>
      </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
            <iframe id="frame-1" src="http://www.facebook.com" width="100%" height="500">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p> </iframe>
            </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
            <iframe src="http://www.google.com" id="frame-2" width="100%" height="500">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>  
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
            <iframe src="url3" width="100%" id="frame-3" height="500">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>  
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
            <iframe  src="url4" id="frame-4">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>  
    </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obviously change the URLs for your URLs but this preLoads the iframe src before you click the tabs...